# Getting error Region name [us-west-1] is not valid [Kinesis streaming integration with spark]

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I have setup spark and trying to run spark submit command using python example for wordcount found [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kinesis-asl/src/main/python/examples/streaming/kinesis_wordcount_asl.py)

Below is the command i run for spark submit:-

```
bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.12:2.4.0  /Users/amitdhawan/Downloads/kinesis_wordcount_asl.py [appname] [streamname] [https://kinesis.us-west-1.amazonaws.com] [us-west-1]
```

The error i get is below:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amitdhawan/Downloads/kinesis_wordcount_asl.py", line 76, in <module>
    ssc, appName, streamName, endpointUrl, regionName, InitialPositionInStream.LATEST, 2)
  File "/Users/amitdhawan/Downloads/spark-2.2.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/kinesis.py", line 92, in createStream
  File "/Users/amitdhawan/Downloads/spark-2.2.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/Users/amitdhawan/Downloads/spark-2.2.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o28.createStream.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Region name '[us-west-1]' is not valid
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisUtils$.$anonfun$validateRegion$2(KinesisUtils.scala:561)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisUtils$.validateRegion(KinesisUtils.scala:561)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisUtils$.$anonfun$createStream$1(KinesisUtils.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.withNamedScope(StreamingContext.scala:274)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisUtils$.createStream(KinesisUtils.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisUtils$.createStream(KinesisUtils.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kinesis.KinesisUtilsPythonHelper.createStream(KinesisUtils.scala:614)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Not sure why im getting region as not valid as i have made sure my Kinesis stream and app exists in us-west-1 from aws-console.

EDIT:-

Now im getting error in below command for running kinesis stream

```
bin/run-example streaming.KinesisWordProducerASL streamname https://kinesis.us-west-1.amazonaws.com 1000 10
```

Error is:-

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.KinesisWordProducerASL
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Not sure how can i register this class. I also provided the --class param in spark submit command but that also not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved it by using the command as below:-

```
bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11:2.4.0  /Users/amitdhawan/Downloads/kinesis_wordcount_asl.py appname streamname https://kinesis.us-west-1.amazonaws.com us-west-1
```

Observe the square brackets are removed and also downgraded scala from 2.12 to 2.11